# Read response from server using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax

Hi i am doing robot controlling project which send Get request "http//:10.0.1.1/forward" command to the java server in the robot and the server response with "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nOK\r\n" indicate the server received the request. My question is how to read the response("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nOK\r\n") from the server in ajax

Following is my index.html hosted in xampp

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

var page = 'http://10.0.1.1/forward;
xmlhttp.open('GET', page, true); 
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Following is the java server:

```
        ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        sock = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("server ");
        //get stream to send and receive data
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);


            String reply = execute(cmd); //this function return "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"
            if (reply != null){
              ps.println(reply);
            }
            else {
              br.close();
              ps.close();
              break;
            }
```

Where does the print stream print the reply in here? html? how to read this reply in index.html?

I have tried this way

```
document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML=xmlhttp.status;
document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML=xmlhttp.statusText;
document.getElementById('A3').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

what i get from xmlhttp.status is 0. But when i tried the tutorial it has the following code

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML=xmlhttp.status;
    document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML=xmlhttp.statusText;
    document.getElementById('A3').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

However it does not satisfy the condition, i am kind of stuck for a few days and desperately need help.

Comment: i think your issue is in the response format, it could be not HTTp proper response, check this question, check the very last answer, it holds the response how it should be formated, `\r\n` between values and `\r\n\r\n` at end of headers, and some extra headers like content type, content-length... check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638848/trouble-sending-http-response-with-java-socket

Comment: Hello, i am trying to read the response sent from the server and print at the html page.

I am referring to the source code of this page:
http://lejosnews.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/httyr-browser-control/

at the server it has send the reply back to html:
line 52: ps.println(reply);

but how to read the reply in html page?