# How to write HTTP response using java socket

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to write the standard response message to my brower when the browser connects, but the results do not display on my browser.

Here is the code

```
Socket sock;

PrintWriter writeSock;

BufferedReader readSock;
writeSock = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);
writeSock.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + "Hello world");
```

do I print to the writeSock to get it to show on the browser? I'm confused at how to put a standard HTTP response in java.

Comment: The server is a currently working standard socket server.  This is just the shorthand where I am trying to write the response message

Comment: Honestly, google is your friend

Comment: A simple google search with the title of your question would have sent you to another similar question here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638848/trouble-sending-http-response-with-java-socket

Answer (score 0):

You need a blank line between the headers and the body of the response. Something like

```
writeSock.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello world");
```

However, you'll want to read the HTTP specification to understand additional headers that should be sent with the response, like content-type.