# localhost not sending data in HTTP response in socket program

Tags: sockets

I'm writing an HTTP server and client in python. When I run my scripts for client and server in terminal everything works fine. However, when I go to my browser and type "localhost:12000" in the searchbar, I get an error saying "The page isn't working. localhost didn't send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". What I expect to see instead, is the content of the html file contained in the response message.

This is the code for my HTTP client.

```
from socket import *

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 18000

clientSocket.connect(("localhost",serverPort))

request = "GET www.somepage/index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.somepage.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Chrome/86.0.4240.183\r\nAccept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\nAccept-Language: it-IT, en-US\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8\r\n"


print(request)

clientSocket.send(request.encode())

response = (clientSocket.recv(1024)).decode()

print(response)

clientSocket.close()
```

This is the code for my server.

```
from socket import *
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import calendar

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

serverSocket.bind(("localhost",serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

current_date = calendar.day_abbr[date.today().weekday()]+", "+date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y")+strftime(" %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+ " GMT"

while True:
    connection , addr = serverSocket.accept()
    request = (connection.recv(1024)).decode()
    request = request.split()
    method = request[0]
    URL = request[1]
    version = request[2]
    if method == "GET" and URL == "www.somepage/index.html" and version == "HTTP/1.0":
        response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: {}\r\nServer: Apache\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020, 6:31:00 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 72 bytes\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n<html>\r\n<title>PAGE TITLE</title>\r\n<body>\rThis is the body\r\n</body></html>".format(current_date)
        connection.send(response.encode())
        connection.close()
```

So the server is checking if the request line is correct and then sending the HTTP response, which I do see in the terminal, but when I try in the browser I get an error instead. I've also tried checking Wireshark and I do see the HTTP messages there, so I don't understand why my browsers says no data has been sent.

Thank you all for your help.

Edit:

I couldn't post my code in the comment so I'll try here. What I'm trying to do is create an HTTP client and server than don't implement the entire HTTP protocol, but just a few request methods and a few replies. For now I was starting with the GET method and the 200 OK reply.

This is the code for my client. I have added an extra \r\n at the end of the header in the request.

```
from socket import *

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

clientSocket.connect(("localhost",serverPort))

request = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \r\nHost: www.somepage.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Chrome/86.0.4240.183\r\nAccept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\nAccept-Language: it-IT, en-US\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8\r\n\r\n"


print(request)

clientSocket.send(request.encode())

response = (clientSocket.recv(1024)).decode()

print(response)

clientSocket.close()
```

This is the code for my server, with an added \r\n at the end of header as well.

```
from socket import *
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import calendar

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

serverSocket.bind(("localhost",serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

current_date = calendar.day_abbr[date.today().weekday()]+", "+date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y")+strftime(" %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+ " GMT"

while True:
    connection , addr = serverSocket.accept()
    request = (connection.recv(1024)).decode()
    request = request.split()
    method = request[0]
    URI = request[1]
    version = request[2]
    host = request[4]
    if method == "GET" and URI == "/index.html" and version == "HTTP/1.0" and host == "www.somepage.com":
        response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: {}\r\nServer: Apache\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020, 6:31:00 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 83 bytes\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<title>PAGE TITLE</title>\r\n<body>\rThis is the body\r\n</body></html>".format(current_date)
        connection.send(response.encode())
    connection.close()
```

I've studied the standard and I'm trying to write my code according to the specifications. What I see in my browser is this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhuP0.png)

I've also noticed that if I change my server code to this:

```
from socket import *
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import calendar

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

serverSocket.bind(("localhost",serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

current_date = calendar.day_abbr[date.today().weekday()]+", "+date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y")+strftime(" %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+ " GMT"

while True:
    connection , addr = serverSocket.accept()
    request = (connection.recv(1024)).decode()
    request = request.split()
    method = request[0]
    URI = request[1]
    version = request[2]
    host = request[4]
    if "GET" in request:
        response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: {}\r\nServer: Apache\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020, 6:31:00 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 83 bytes\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<title>PAGE TITLE</title>\r\n<body>\rThis is the body\r\n</body></html>".format(current_date)
        connection.send(response.encode())
    connection.close()
```

where basically the only difference is the way the if statement is written, then my browser will display correctly the html, that is, I see this:

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ46q.png)

So it seems the problem lies in the syntax I used for my python code, and not the way the standard is implemented?
Thank you again so very much for your help.

---

I couldn't post my code in the comment so I'll try here. What I'm trying to do is create an HTTP client and server than don't implement the entire HTTP protocol, but just a few request methods and a few replies. For now I was starting with the GET method and the 200 OK reply.

This is the code for my client. I have added an extra \r\n at the end of the header in the request.

```
from socket import *

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

clientSocket.connect(("localhost",serverPort))

request = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \r\nHost: www.somepage.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Chrome/86.0.4240.183\r\nAccept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\nAccept-Language: it-IT, en-US\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8\r\n\r\n"


print(request)

clientSocket.send(request.encode())

response = (clientSocket.recv(1024)).decode()

print(response)

clientSocket.close()
```

This is the code for my server, with an added \r\n at the end of header as well.

```
from socket import *
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import calendar

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

serverSocket.bind(("localhost",serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

current_date = calendar.day_abbr[date.today().weekday()]+", "+date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y")+strftime(" %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+ " GMT"

while True:
    connection , addr = serverSocket.accept()
    request = (connection.recv(1024)).decode()
    request = request.split()
    method = request[0]
    URI = request[1]
    version = request[2]
    host = request[4]
    if method == "GET" and URI == "/index.html" and version == "HTTP/1.0" and host == "www.somepage.com":
        response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: {}\r\nServer: Apache\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020, 6:31:00 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 83 bytes\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<title>PAGE TITLE</title>\r\n<body>\rThis is the body\r\n</body></html>".format(current_date)
        connection.send(response.encode())
    connection.close()
```

I've studied the standard and I'm trying to write my code according to the specifications. What I see in my browser is this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhuP0.png)

I've also noticed that if I change my server code to this:

```
from socket import *
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import calendar

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 12000

serverSocket.bind(("localhost",serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

current_date = calendar.day_abbr[date.today().weekday()]+", "+date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y")+strftime(" %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+ " GMT"

while True:
    connection , addr = serverSocket.accept()
    request = (connection.recv(1024)).decode()
    request = request.split()
    method = request[0]
    URI = request[1]
    version = request[2]
    host = request[4]
    if "GET" in request:
        response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: {}\r\nServer: Apache\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020, 6:31:00 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 83 bytes\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<title>PAGE TITLE</title>\r\n<body>\rThis is the body\r\n</body></html>".format(current_date)
        connection.send(response.encode())
    connection.close()
```

where basically the only difference is the way the if statement is written, then my browser will display correctly the html, that is, I see this:

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ46q.png)

So it seems the problem lies in the syntax I used for my python code, and not the way the standard is implemented?
Thank you again so very much for your help.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638848/trouble-sending-http-response-with-java-socket

Comment: @SrđanPopić Thank you. However, I'm still not able to identify a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> request = "GET www.somepage/index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.somepage.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Chrome/86.0.4240.183\r\nAccept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\nAccept-Language: it-IT, en-US\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8\r\n"
> ```

This is not a valid HTTP request. First, it should only contain the path `/index.html` and not `domain/path` as you currently do. It is also missing the final `\r\n` at the end which signals the end of the HTTP header.

In the same way the expectations of the server wrong too, which explains why it causes problems when faced with a client correctly implementing HTTP (the browser). Additionally the HTTP response  is also missing the final `\r\n` after the HTTP header and the `Content-length: 72` does not match the actual length of the content.

Please don't implement HTTP by (wrongly) second-guessing how it works. There is an actual standard for this and implementations are expected to follow this standard.

After the edit the code looks like this:

```
request = request.split()
...
version = request[2]
host = request[4]
if method == "GET" and URI == "/index.html" and version == "HTTP/1.0" and host == "www.somepage.com":
   ... send response ...
```

There are multiple problems here: the first one is that the browser will not use `HTTP/1.0` as version but `HTTP/1.1`.

The next problem is  that the domain might not be in the variable `host` since it is might not be in `request[4]`. It is blindly assumed that the `Host` header is in the second line of the request since it is implemented like this in the client. But the HTTP standard does in now way require this. And while it might be the case with some clients it is not the case with others. Instead of blindly assuming that something is in a specific place in the HTTP header the header should actually be parsed properly to extract the `Host` header.

Comment: Namely RFC 2616 and successors.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've applied the changes to the request line in the client script so that it has just the path /index.html in the URI field. I've also modified the server so that now it also checks if the host header is www.somepage.com, since the host header is mandatory as explained here tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4 , correct?
You also mentioned adding \r\n at the end of the request but it's already there.
As for the content length, I calculated the length of this
<html>\r\n<title>PAGE TITLE</title>\r\n<body>\r\nThis is the body\r\n</body></html>
which appears to be 83 bytes.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich even with these changes I still get the same error in the browser. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: @AnnaDiNardo: I have no way to reproduce how the code "with these changes" looks like. Also, did you already study the standard or do you still implement protocols by try and error? Note that the latter approach might lead to a wrong implementation which works with the few clients you test but later causes strange problems with others.

Comment: @AnnaDiNardo: *"You also mentioned adding \r\n at the end of the request but it's already there."* - no, it's not. There is a line ending for the last header field but there is no __additional__ `\r\n` to mark the end of the HTTP header. Again, follow the standard instead of second-guessing the protocol.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have posted an answer so I can show you my code. I apoligize, but I'm new to this website. Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to me.

Comment: @AnnaDiNardo: see updated answer. You're assumptions on how HTTP works were again wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you so much again for your answer. The reason why I assumed that the host header would be the first after the request line is because it says here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4 . The section reads:
"Since the Host field-value is critical information for handling a request, a user agent SHOULD generate Host as the first header field following the request-line."

Comment: @AnnaDiNardo: Interesting find. But unfortunately this is a SHOULD and not a MUST :( I also found another problem (answer updated): you expect the version to be HTTP/1.0 but it is actually HTTP/1.1. I recommend that you print out the request to actually show what you get before getting assumptions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see. Thank you, you have been most helpful.